# HTTP get request basic authentication?

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework

I am trying to do a basic authentication get request in Angular Ionic.
I am passing username and password from my side to the server and trying to get a CSRF token and a session Id. But I get a 500 internal server error.
So I am using this method to login:

```
public login(username: string, password: string): Observable<Object>{
  return this.httpClient.get(`myUrl`,{
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: "Basic" +  window.btoa(username + ':' + password)
    })
  });
}
```

I think I should use httpInterceptor to intercept the request, can anyone tell how to do that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: First issue I see is there should be a space after the `"Basic"` literal. It should be `"Basic " + ...`

Comment: Yes with that it changes the error, it's 404 now, and it opens another login windows after my actual app login page. Can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put a **space** after basic:

```
Authorization: "Basic " +  window.btoa(username + ':' + password)
```

Comment: I tried but no, it opens another login window where it asks me an username and password again

Comment: Yes now it's different, but it's strange that there is this new pop up window now, I can't understand why.

Comment: I mean my friend, I gave the answer to the question you asked, and you are not getting 500 errors now, the rest is a different problem and you have to create a separate question for it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with how your server expects the data to be and how the device is sending the data to the server. Because of this mismatch, the server is not able to process the data and is bugging out.

Depending upon your server endpoint configuration, another way of doing it could be, the authentication data is not sent in the headers. Your login api call could look like this.

```
 login(login, password): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(`myUrl`, {
            login_id : login,
            password : password
        });
    }
```

Your server then authenticates the user and responds back with a authentication token (CSRFToken) which you then pass in the header for the api call.

I suggest that you spend some time in implementing the HTTP request interceptor in your app. Going forward, when the application has to hit multiple api's, you won't have to add the token individually for all the api calls.

```
if (this.globalConst.authToken) {
  newHeader['Authorization-Key'] =this.globalConst.authToken;
  request = request.clone({
    setHeaders: newHeader
  });
}
return next.handle(request);
```

[Tutorial](https://blog.angulartraining.com/http-interceptors-in-angular-61dcf80b6bdd)